# c# Excel add-in get Cell position on screen

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I'm having a trouble in getting a cell's position on screen.
I'm developing an Excel add-in using VSTO.
I tried almost every code I found, and none of them worked.

I'm trying to show a popup form for the user when he focuses on specific cell.
I could get everything to work properly, However I'm unable to place the form correctly. How can I get the cell's Top/Left in order to set the Form's Top/Left?

I want the code to also account for the case when the user has scrolled the sheet (up/down/left/right).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anycode you can show?

Comment: I use 
Application.SheetSelectionChange += xlApp_SheetSelectionChange;

and in 
'
private void xlApp_SheetSelectionChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
{
int row=Application.ActiveCell.Row;
int col=Application.ActiveCell.Column;
Form popup = new Form();
            popup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            popup.Left = Convert.ToInt32(currentSheet.Cells[row, col].Left) ;
            
            popup.Top = Convert.ToInt32(currentSheet.Cells[row, col].Top );
            popup.Show();
}

'